# Locating points based on location and attribute difference using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, query, proximity

I am not sure if this is feasible or not but here is what I am looking to do:

I have a point feature class where a certain set of the points all fall within 10-15 feet of another point. Ideally, those two points would share the same attribute value (address).

How do I locate all the points that are within 15 feet of another point **but** only the points that DO NOT have a matching address?

Comment: Do a spatial join.  Then with the results, select or query on the records that do not have an address in the second address field.